# Parse a month name and create a date range

Tags: scala, date, jodatime

Given the current year and a an arbitrary month in a full string format ("april"), how do I create a date range for this month? For example, if I'm given "june" I want to create 
`date1 = "2014-06-01"` and d`ate2 = "2014-06-31"`. I tried to parse a month:

```
DateTime.parse("january")
DateTime.parse("2014-january")
DateTime.parse("2014-january-01")
```

but it caused the error saying its argument was wrong. I could use another overloaded version of parse but it turned out to be pretty difficult due to its [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) parameters which I had no idea how to use.

I could create a map containing all months and the amount of days they, but since [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)  has a standard way to do that I decided not to do that.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not that well versed with scala but since it's `JVM`, I will give it a shot, correct me if I make any syntax errors:

```
var strDate = "January"
var format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM")
var date = format.parseDateTime(strDate)
println(date)

var monthStart = new DateTime().withYear(2014).withMonthOfYear(date.getMonthOfYear()).withDayOfMonth(date.dayOfMonth().getMinimumValue())
var monthEnd = new DateTime().withYear(2014).withMonthOfYear(date.getMonthOfYear()).withDayOfMonth(date.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue())

println("Month Start : " + monthStart)
println("Month End : " + monthEnd)
```

Without the year, jodatime would default to 2000 hence while setting the `monthStart` and `monthEnd` I set it to 2014 explicitly.

In Java, I get the output like:

```
Month Start : 2014-01-01T15:00:26.174+05:30
Month End : 2014-01-31T15:00:26.179+05:30
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Minor suggestion: I would name that variable "datetime" or "dateTime" rather than "date" to avoid confusion with java.util.Date.

Comment: I would add an explicit DateTimeZone object. Otherwise the time-of-day will be according to the JVM's default time zone. So the same code running on different computers/JVMs or changed time zone setting will emit different results. Probably not what you would want. Add a call to `withZone` after the call to `forPattern`.

Comment: I would name that variable "format" as "formatter". The [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) class is a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for emitting [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instances.

Comment: What's up with your output having seconds and fractional seconds? Is [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) not setting the time to start of day? Those particular numbers seem odd to me. At any rate, perhaps you should add calls to [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()).

Comment: @BasilBourque Can I just get away by saying it was "quick-and-dirty"? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import java.util.Locale

val dt = "2014-january-01"
val df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MMMMM-dd").withLocale(Locale.US)
DateTime.parse(dt, df)
```

This gives you:

```
res16: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

Then, you may do something like this:

```
val start = res16.dayOfMonth.withMinimumValue
val end = res16.dayOfMonth.withMaximumValue
```

Comment: I think res16 and start are the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just showed how you can get the start and the end of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it would be better if you could be passed a month number rather than a localized month name. But if you have no way to change that, here we go with some example code in Java using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

You'll have to adjust syntax to Scala on your own.

My code here was inspired by the [answer by PopoFibo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21750223/642706).

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Macau" );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );

// Gather inputs
int currentYear = now.getYear();
String givenMonth = "april";
String doubleDigitOne = new java.text.DecimalFormat( "00" ).format( 1 );

// Assemble inputs
String input = currentYear + "-" + givenMonth + "-" + doubleDigitOne;

// Parse inputs.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MMM-dd" ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH ).withZone( timeZone );
DateTime monthStart = formatter.parseDateTime( input );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "monthStart: " + monthStart );
System.out.println( "monthStart in UTC/GMT: " + monthStart.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-02-13T21:12:01.901+08:00
input: 2014-april-01
monthStart: 2014-04-01T00:00:00.000+08:00
monthStart in UTC/GMT: 2014-03-31T16:00:00.000Z
```

That solves your funky problem of being passed a month name.

As for defining a span of time representing the entire month… You can search StackOverflow for *many* already-answered questions on that topic including several long explanatory ones by me. Search for terms like: *joda, start of month, start of week, half-open, inclusive, exclusive*. Hint: **Interval** is your new friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.LocalDate

def monthDateRange(month:String) = {
    val ld = LocalDate.parse(month, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM"))
    val end = ld.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1).getDayOfMonth
    (1,end)
}
```